# Get an entire flow logs in Grails with Log4j

Tags: grails, log4j, rollingfileappender

Lets assume I have a cron job class as SampleTestJob which will get the list of admins by calling the utilService findAllAdmins method. 
In each of these classes there are logs added.
I need to get the logs for this entire flow to be printed to a separate log file. 
For that I have used RollingFileAppender using TimeBasedRollingPolicy so that every day will be create a back up of the zip.
In the Config.groovy i have listed the class names for this entire flow such as SampleTestJob, UtilService.
When SampleTestJob is executed logs of SampleTestJob and UtilService will be printed to my log file.
My problem is, i only want the entire flow of SampleTestJob to be printed and yes it gets printed. 
But when findAllAdmins is called by another class in this example by AdminController also it gets printed in the same log file. 
How do i stop this? Is there a better way to implement this?

Also without listing down the classes as `["grails.app.jobs.SampleTestJob", "grails.app.services.UtilService"]` for the entire flow is there a way it could identify and print all the logs to the log file.

```
class SampleTestJob{

def utilService

def execute() {
    log.info "Beginning SampleTestJob."
    List<Admin> adminList = utilService.findAllAdmins()//Calling the findAllAdmins of utilService.
    log.info "Finished SampleTestJob."

}
}

class UtilService{

def findAllAdmins() {
    log.info "Beginning findAllAdmins."
    //Implementation to get all the admins
    log.info "Finished findAllAdmins."
}
}

class AdminController{

def utilService

def listAdmins() {
    log.info "Beginning listAdmins."
    List<Admin> adminList = utilService.findAllAdmins()//Calling the findAllAdmins of utilService.
    log.info "Finished listAdmins."
}
}
```

def sampleTestJob = new SampleTestJob()
sampleTestJob.execute()

**Config.groovy**

```
log4j = {

def logDir = 'target' + '/logs'
def logPattern = '%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} %x - %m%n'

def jobRollingFile   = new RollingFileAppender(name: 'SampleLogs', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: logPattern))
def jobRollingPolicy = new TimeBasedRollingPolicy(fileNamePattern: "$logDir/Logs/Sample.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz", activeFileName: "$logDir/Logs/Sample.log")
jobRollingPolicy.activateOptions()
jobRollingFile.setRollingPolicy jobRollingPolicy

appenders {
    appender jobRollingFile
}

info additivity: false, SampleLogs   : ["grails.app.jobs.SampleTest", "grails.app.services.UtilService"]

}
```